# How to get request and response from Web Api and save it to the database

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

I have a method in the Controller class below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(RsContractCustomer))]
    [Route("api/Contract/GetCustomerData/{cardModificationId}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCustomerData([FromUri] int cardModificationId)
    {
        var jsonIgnoreNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(await _bs.GetCustomer(cardModificationId), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        });

        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonIgnoreNullValues);
        return Ok(jObject); //await _bs.GetCustomerData(id));
    }
```

Now I want to get `HttpResponseMessage` and save particular part into database. What I should to add in these code or implement middleware to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpReponseMessage is received in the client side (Middleware and controllers are on the server side).

In the client project you can write something like that:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:8080/api/contract/getcustomerdata/1");

        var customer = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RsContractCustomer>();

        // Save to DB
```